# Try to pull an image from docker cloud without tag specified

Tags: docker

Following this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#pull-and-run-the-image-from-the-remote-repository), I'm currently trying to pull an image which uploaded to docker cloud earlier on, to be specific, the uploaded image was associated/tagged with **part2**.

[image]

The part that I don't understand is it says

> Note: If you don’t specify the :tag portion of these commands, the tag of :latest will be assumed, both when you build and when you run images. Docker will use the last version of the image that ran without a tag specified (not necessarily the most recent image).

I gave it a try as shown below

[image]

As shown from the result, it seems that it's looking for a specific tag with title `latest` instead. Am I looking at the wrong direction or understood the context wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link should help you understand more about docker tag.
https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375

In short, latest is just a tag with a special name. 
In the tutorial you posted, if you look closely, in the dockerhub repository, there is an image with the tag latest which is also mentioned. 
[image: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#tag-the-image]

If the repository does not have an image with the tag 'latest', you should hit the error as you showed.

**Also not that you will be specify multiple tags when building an image.**

Few more samples of images with the tag latest listed can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/redis/tags/). You can explore more from the official dockerhub repository.